# Responsive columns not displaying correctly on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a four-column footer, which collapses into two columns on tablets, and one column on mobile devices.

The viewport metatag and stylesheets are as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/tablet.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 960px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 640px)">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, width=device-width">
```

The responsiveness works fine when changing the screen size on desktop, as seen here:

- [Tablet, as viewed on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kty1.png)
- [Mobile, as viewed on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XMZP.png)

However, on a mobile device, the footer columns appear as two columns, not one:

- [Website on mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1MVN.png)

Here is the css from `main.css`:

```
div#footer div.wrapper div.column {
    float: none !important;
    display: table-cell;
    width:25%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
```

Here is the css from `tablet.css`:

```
div#footer { padding: 10px; }

div#footer div.wrapper div.column { width:50%; margin-bottom: 20px; border: none; float: left !important; }
div#footer div.wrapper div.column:nth-child(3) {
    clear:both;
}
```

...and here is the css from `mobile.css`:

```
div#footer { padding: 10px; }
    div.column {
        width:100% !important;
        float:none !important;
    }
```

And finally the HTML (with placeholder text):

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="column">
            <h4>Important Links</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="/terms">Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h4>Important Links</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="/terms">Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h4>Important Links</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="/terms">Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>
        <div class="column" style="border-right: none;" >           
            <h4>Header</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How can I ensure that mobile devices display the formatting from `mobile.css`, like it does when I simulate a mobile device on my desktop browser?**

---

**Update**: The following, updated `mobile.css` css code still results in two columns:

```
div.column {
    width:100% !important;
    float:none !important;
    clear: both !important;
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: why do you use a different class on main.css then mobile i.e. `div#footer div.wrapper div.column` for main? and `div.column` for mobile?

Comment: `div.column` applies to columns from different sections on the site that may have different widths in main, however *every* column on the site becomes 100% width when viewed on mobile.

Comment: have you got a external link i can take a quick look at i think i know why but dont want to answer for it to get shut down lol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had weird issues with `display: table-cell;` before. For the mobile css try reiterating the tablet styles and `display: block;`

```
div#footer { padding: 10px; }
div#footer div.wrapper div.column:nth-child(3) {
    width:100% !important;
    float:none !important;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I edited my code a little. In the tablet css you set the footer and wrapper and third  column to 50% and only change the column back not the footer or wrapper. That could possibly be the issue?? See if the edited code works.

Comment: It ended up being the `display: block` that fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to mobile.css

```
div#footer div.wrapper div.column {
    display: block;
}
```

When you use display: table-cell it causes < div > to act like a < td > elements

Answer (score 1):

take off you `float:none !Important` and it will work

try this for mobile CSS.

```
div#footer { padding: 10px; }
div#footer div.wrapper div.column {
        width:100% !important;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow, this results in *four* columns, not one - unfortunately a step backwards!

Comment: take off your `float:none!important` should be fine then edited my answer @BenPearlKahan just tried it in browser

Comment: Still no luck - back to two columns; square one!

Comment: you must have a cached version!! @BenPearlKahan i can see it in front of me now!

Comment: I keep clearing the cache before *every* refresh - are you looking on desktop, or on a mobile device? I'm using an iPhone 5, is it mobile specific?

Comment: i have viewed it on iphone 5 and it is working.. try another browser on the iPhone or delete history?

Comment: It's working in Safari now. Not chrome. Could be a rendering issue in Chrome for iOS... Been clearing the cache each refresh. Thank you for your help!